# nginx: how limit_req_zone zone gets cleared?

Tags: nginx, throttling

According to nginx documentation on **limit_req_zone**

> One megabyte zone can keep about 16 thousand 64-byte states. If the zone storage is exhausted, the server will return the 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable) error to all further requests.

I wonder in what way these zones get cleared? For example if we have smth like

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:1m rate=1r/s;
```

and the number of unique users per a day exceeds 16000 - does it mean that the zone will get overflown and other users will start getting 503 error for the set up location? Or is there a time frame of user's inactivity after which the-user-related-zone-memory will be cleaned?

My main concern here is to set an optimal zone size without a risk of getting it exhausted
in case of high-load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be checked, but as I understood lifetime of the zone items relates to the active connections.
So `zone=one:1m` can hold up to **16 K unique IPs** among currently (simultaneously) **active connections** (total number of the active connections at the moment can exceed 16 K, because a few connections can be opened from the same IP).
So zone size in mb should be >= number of simultaneous connections from the unique IPs / 16K.

**Note** that if users share single IP over the NAT that is rather often for USSR providers then you will *limit request frequency for the bunch of users* that can be very inconvenient for them, so to handle this case you should set **rate = simult_users_with_same_ip** r/s

Answer (score 3):

#### From https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx

> If storage is exhausted when NGINX needs to add a new entry, it removes the oldest entry. If the space freed is still not enough to accommodate the new record, NGINX returns status code `503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable)`. Additionally, to prevent memory from being exhausted, **every time NGINX creates a new entry it removes up to two entries that have not been used in the previous 60 seconds.**

＞16K entries a day is nothing to worry about. NGINX wipes entries that are inactive for more than a minute.

But if the number of ***active*** entries reaches ＞16K, it gets problematic, in that [it might lose entries (and states) in use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67787464/could-a-small-limit-req-zone-zone-size-compromise-rate-limiting)